# убрать border при нажатии

Tags: html, css, html5

Есть следующий код:

```css
.btn {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-decoration: none;
    animation: border-pulsate 2s infinite;
    border: 2px solid black;
    transition: .5s;
}

@keyframes border-pulsate {
    0%   { border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); }
    50%  { border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); }
    100% { border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); }
}
```

```html
<a class="btn" href="#open-modal"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/36/36601.svg"></a>
```

Ссылка просто открывает модальное окно. Как мне посредством javascript (или, если есть способ, CSS) при нажатии на кнопку убрать анимацию border'a?

Comment: `$('.btn').click(function(){$('.btn').css({"animation-name":"none"})});` Ну или `animation-name` заменить на `border`

Comment: Спасибо, все работает!

Comment: всегда пожалуйста:)

Answer (score 2):

С css будет костыльно лучше через Js

```js
var btn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');

for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
btn[i].onclick = function(){this.style.animation = "none";}
}
```

```css
.btn {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-decoration: none;
    animation: border-pulsate 2s infinite;
    border: 2px solid red;
    transition: .5s;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    
}

@keyframes border-pulsate {
    0%   { border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); }
    50%  { border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); }
    100% { border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); }
}
```

```html
<a class="btn" href="#open-modal"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/36/36601.svg"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.btn:active{
  border:none;
}
```

это css вариант

Answer (score 1):

```
<a class="btn" href="#open-modal" onclick="this.style.border="none"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

еще как вариант

```css
.btn {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-decoration: none;
    animation: border-pulsate 2s infinite;
    border: 2px solid black;
    transition: .5s;
}
@keyframes border-pulsate {
    0%   { border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); }
    50%  { border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); }
    100% { border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); }
}

.btn:focus{ 
  animation: border-pulsate-stop 2s infinite;
}
@keyframes border-pulsate-stop {
    0%   { border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); }    
    100% { border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); }
}
```

```html
<a class="btn" href="#open-modal"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/36/36601.svg"></a>
```